# Count Paths for a Sum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

Apologies if this kind of question is not allowed here.

I came across this question: "Given a binary tree and a number ‘S’, find all paths in the tree such that the sum of all the node values of each path equals ‘S’. Please note that the paths can start or end at any node but all paths must follow direction from parent to child (top to bottom).". I solved it by trying to include the parents and not include the parents through recursion.

I am struggling to determine the time/space complexity for my answer and whether or not my answer is correct. Can you please help me?

I have attached an example along with my answer. Thanks in advance

[image: example]
[image: solution]

Comment: ur solution complexity: 4^(depth_of_tree).

Comment: Question says : *Please note that the paths can start or end at any node* But it seems in your code you count only when you reach a leaf. You need to clarify that.

Comment: @SomeDude aplogies, I attached an older version of my solution by accident. Now I corrected it (hopefully), right?

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib many thanks